# Bayesian Information Criterion -- what is the base of the logarithm?

Tags: dimensionality-reduction

Apologies in advance for a very basic question! On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_information_criterion), I see that the Bayesian Information Criterion evaluates a model using
$$
BIC = k\ln(n)- 2\ln(L)
$$
where $k$ is the number of parameters, $n$ the sample size and $L$ the (maximised) likelihood. In the [original paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-statistics/volume-6/issue-2/Estimating-the-Dimension-of-a-Model/10.1214/aos/1176344136.full), however, I see instead the expression
$$
BIC = k\log(n)- 2\log(L)
$$
Can I check that 'log' here means 'ln' (i.e. base $e$ not say base $10$)? Or does it somehow not matter?

Comment: It is from an exponential distribution family, so I believe it is log base-e.  There are only 2 others in common use: base 10 by engineers, and base 2 by computer scientists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a natural logarithm (log base of e). But, no matter what the log is, the most important thing you need to remember is to compare models under a consistent kind of logarithm.

Comment: "the most important thing you need to remember is to compare models under a consistent kind of logarithm". Should I take this to mean that I can use a different base provided that the base I use is the same for all models?

Comment: Yes, that is what I want to say.